# Doctrine left join on unrelated entity

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm

Is there any way to do this. I'm getting more and more confused trying different things.

I have an entity conferences that can have a place. 
Places are in a many to one relationship with city.

In my query I'm trying to retrieve the city info but can't seem to retrieve it in the same place result.
This is the query used:

```
$qbt = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
$qbt
    ->select('conference', 'diffusion', 'speaker', 'placediff', 'confcity')
    ->from('AppBundle:Conference', 'conference')
    ->leftJoin('conference.diffusion', 'diffusion')
    ->leftJoin('conference.speaker','speaker')
    ->leftJoin('conference.place','placediff')
    ->leftJoin('AppBundle:City', 'confcity', 'WITH', 'confcity.id = placediff.city');

return $qbt
    ->getQuery()
    ->setHint(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HINT_INCLUDE_META_COLUMNS, true)
    ->useQueryCache(true)
    ->useResultCache(true, 3600)
    ->getArrayResult();
```

This is what is returns, currently have only one conference. 
Would love to have the second array inside place though.

[image: query result]

Any ideas on how to accomplish this? Much obliged ~

(UPDATE) In the meantime I switched to raw sql query but really looking for a way to do this using dql

```
    public function rawConf()
    {
        $conn = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection();
        $sql = 'SELECT
  c0_.id AS id,
  c0_.startAt AS startat,
  c0_.comment AS comment,
  d1_.id AS diffusion_id,
  d1_.hour AS diffusion_hour,
  s2_.id AS speaker_id,
  c0_.place_id AS place_id,
  c0_.sponsor_id AS sponsor_id,
  c0_.tour_id AS tour_id_8,
  d1_.movie_id AS diffusion_movie_id,
  s2_.contact_id AS speaker_contact_id,
  c6_.name AS ville_name,
  c6_.postal AS ville_post,
  c6_.department as ville_depart
FROM
  conference c0_
  LEFT JOIN conference_diffusion c3_ ON c0_.id = c3_.conference_id
  LEFT JOIN diffusion d1_ ON d1_.id = c3_.diffusion_id
  LEFT JOIN conference_speaker c4_ ON c0_.id = c4_.conference_id
  LEFT JOIN speaker s2_ ON s2_.id = c4_.speaker_id
  LEFT JOIN place p5_ ON c0_.place_id = p5_.id
  LEFT JOIN city c6_ ON (c6_.id = p5_.city_id)';

        $stmt = $conn->prepare($sql);

        $stmt->execute();

        return $stmt->fetchAll();

    }
```

Comment: Update  =>    Apparently can return the result as >getResult(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_SCALAR) and it merges all the properties. Anything I should be aware of doing this?

Comment: Hmm no go , the SCALAR HYDRATE duplicates columns

Comment: Post your updates in the original post by editing it not commenting. Also your image is too small to understand what is written there. You can post cropped image here or post preview image that is link to full-size image. But you also can post this output in the post body.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should get "city" from "place" as "$city" is a property of Place entity. Try this simplified query to see it works:

```
$qbt = $this->_em->createQueryBuilder();
$qbt
    ->select('conference')
    ->addSelect('place')
    ->addSelect('city')
    ->from('AppBundle:Conference', 'conference')
    ->innerJoin('conference.place', 'place')
    ->innerJoin('place.city', 'city')
;
```

And if it works - you could easily add more joins if you need.